# How to access a variable globally?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm expanding my application with an `AccountManager` (as I call it). The application has a login form (it's a different form than the main form) and the information entered here will be `set` to the `AccountManager` class:

```
AccountManager AM = new AccountManager();
AM.username = "Username";
AM.password = "myPassword";
```

But, now the (probably obvious) issue is, I can't grab this information on the main form (since I call `new AccountManager();` so it will start a new instance of the `AccountManager`.

How can I use the class (`AccountManager`) globally? Or would I just have make them public variables with the `static` attribute?

Comment: That doesn't has anything to do with his question...

Comment: First of all you need to learn about separation of Business Logic and User Interface. there is absolutely no reason for this to be on any Form, only (maybe) returned from the "login form". none of this should be global either. Moreover this concept has been implemented at least 20000000000 times in the .Net world already.

Comment: Is this a Windows app or a Web app (ASP.NET)?  Be aware that in ASP.NET static classes are shared between ALL user sessions.

Comment: @DStanley Windows application.

Answer (score 3):

Create an internal static singleton instance of your account manager:

```
public class AccountManager
{
    private static Lazy<AccountManager> _am = new Lazy<AccountManager>();
    internal static AccountManager Current { get { return _am.Value; } }
}
```

This way you can Access a (guaranteed) singleton instance of AccountManager within the current application domain from anywhere in the same assembly:  AccountManager.Current

Look up the constructor methods for Lazy - you can supply a factory method if you want (thereby allowing you to keep the password properly encapsulated) and also you can guarantee thread safety of the factory method.

Also, Lazy means any expensive operations incurred in the construction of your AccountManager object will be delayed until absolutely necessary, which means your app won't use resources until absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably go the singleton way. However the `Lazy<T>` type is not available for my .Net version (`3.5`).

Comment: No problem :)  I recommend upgrading your .NET version if at all possible.

Comment: Could you have a look at my example? My .Net knowledge is quite limited so any help would be appreciated. I have a really minimal project which can be downloaded as a ZIP [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6166898/SingletonExample.zip)

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that today, I'm looking after my 8 month old son and can only be on the computer for a small while, but I could look in a couple of days...?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your AccountManager AM as a parameter to your Login Form e.g.

```
loginForm.Show(AM);
```

and in loginForm there should be something like:

```
AccountManager accountManager = null;
public DialogResult ShowDialog(AccountManager am)
{
accountManager = am;
return this.ShowDialog();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought about this. However I'd go the singleton way so I always have the same instance, so I don't need to create it a specific place first and then keep passing it along.

Comment: Sure the singleton way is nicer if you need your accountmanager instance at a couple of different places in your project. Mix Nathan's an my solution if you want to have an additional assembly with reusable GUI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check below. Account class holds Username and Password. Use AccountManager to initialize Account object once. Use AccountManager.GetAccountInfo() method for getting the Account obj globally.

```
class Account
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

    public Account(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}

class AccountManager
{
    Account acc = null;

    public AccountManager(string username, string password)
    {
        if(acc == null)
        {
            acc = new Account(username, password);
        }
    }

    public Account GetAccountInfo()
    {
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using the following method:

On my `mainForm`, I initiate the `AccountManager`:

```
public static AccountManager AM = new AccountManager();
```

Then, on each form I need to access my `AccountManager`, I use the following piece of code:

```
AccountManager AM = mainForm.AM;
MessageBox.Show(AM.username);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send the variables to the `constructor` of `AccountManager` like the following:

On `Main`:

```
AccountManager AM = new AccountManager(Username, Password);
```

On `AccountManager`:

```
public AccountManager(string username, string password)
{

}
```

Or you could make `AccountManager` a static `class`:

[Static Class MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)